# ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos recent, not all, videos under iOS8

Tags: ios8, alassetslibrary, photokit

Our app lets the user load a video from their camera roll. This is pretty standard stuff:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

// Enumeration over all groups with videos
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock  groupsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if (result) {
             // do stuff here with each video
         }
     }];
};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock: groupsEnumerationBlock
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                         log4Debug(@"No groups found or accessible for Camera Roll.");
                     }
 ];
```

The problem is of course with iOS8. That code enumerates over all the videos under iOS7, but under iOS8 it enumerates over all the recent videos. Videos older than 30 days are not available.

Indeed, when you look at the Photos app under iOS8 you don't even see a Camera Roll anymore, just a "Recently Added" album. Now, there is also a "Videos" album which has all videos. Accessing that would be fine here.

We cannot convert to PhotoKit (today). We'll want to do that soon but right now we need a solution that works with both iOS7 and iOS8.

Comment: I suspect that iOS 8 with the greater reliance on cloud streaming of your photos/videos probably only guarantees the recently added photos/videos are actually on the device. I'd say that's why you can't get at them using the old ALAssets mechanisms. It's a real problem for me too. Guess I'd better start writing some PhotoKit code.

Comment: Note that neither ALAssetsGroupAll nor ALAssetsGroupLibrary works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

PHFetchResult *allPhotosResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:allPhotosOptions];
```

When I tested this on my device it returned all videos I have on the device and not just recent ones.

Comment: This was fixed under iOS8.0.2

Comment: @PaulCezanne failed to notice that question was posted that long ago :)